# wifi driver is not properly working

Tags: wireless

Product name:RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI EXPRESS FAST ETHERNET CONTROLLER,vendor:Realtek semiconductor co ltd,driver:r8169.i do not properly get wifi.it is obtained only when i go near to wifi modem.sometimes it get disconnected.please help.

Comment: You have given details of your ethernet card, not wireless. Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the setting of either the nic card or router> To put them on the same channel, check what channel your router is on and make sure that is (preferably 1, 6, or 11 but it can vary based on EMF nearby). Also, make sure the router is offering the correct frequency and signal. Some devices do not have a/b/g/n while most routers can be configured to work soley for certain ones. So check to see the router supports the frequency connection you have on the nic card. Also, check the Connection Information and see how much bandwidth you're allocating, and that the machine you are on is not associated with any other wireless devices at that time. Lastly, try running sudo service networkmanager restart. Works for me whenever it acts up, but it's only a temporary workaround.

Comment: Wireless interface product:RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Adapter,vendor:Realtek semiconductor Co Ltd,driver:rtl8723be driver version